# Ayuda con consulta SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo esta consulta que me trae las personas que marcaron que desean hacer un curso denominado "noviazgo" pero lo que me gustaría agregar también son los que marcaron otros cursos, por ejemplo "Finanzas", "Jóvenes". esto está relacionado con **respuestas.preguntaid** que trae el id de respuesta. En el caso de esta consulta el id **respuestas.preguntaid = 1734** corresponde al curso de "noviazgo". Me gustaría agregar este ID de respuesta también **"1735", "1736" junto con el que está 1734**. el de **1735 corresponde a "finanzas", el 1736 corresponde a "jóvenes"**
Gracias!

```
select distinct 
Participantes.nombre,Participantes.apellido,Participantes.Cedula,
Participantes.Celular,Preguntas.Descripcion,Respuestas.Contenido,
cursoes.nombre curso
from respuestas, CursoPlaneadoParticipantes, CursoPlaneadoes, 
Participantes,Cursoes, Preguntas
where respuestas.preguntaid = 1734 and  FechaInicio 
BETWEEN '20180317 00:00:00' And '20180317 23:59:59' 
AND Preguntas.Descripcion = 'Noviazgo'
and CursoPlaneadoParticipantes.Id = respuestas.CursoPlaneadoParticipanteId
and CursoPlaneadoes.Id = CursoPlaneadoParticipantes.CursoPlaneadoId
and Participantes.Id = CursoPlaneadoParticipantes.ParticipanteId
and Cursoes.Id = CursoPlaneadoes.CursoId
and Respuestas.Contenido = 'SI'
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, la respuesta lógica es que uses un `IN` en los códigos de la pregunta y no filtres la descripción, ya que no es necesario.

Ahora bien, no puedo contestar sin antes hacer un par de comentarios sobre tu código. Primero que todo, por favor deja de usar joins implícitos (los que fueron deprecados hace más de una década) y uses join explícitos.

También deberías acostumbrarte a usar alias en tus tablas, ya que esto mejora la comprensión del código.

Por último, si tienes una columna de tipo `datetime` o `date` y necesitas filtrar un rango de fechas, **no** uses `BETWEEN` (especialmente si es `datetime`).

Tomando en cuenta lo anterior, el código sería el siguiente:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
            p.nombre,
            p.apellido,
            p.Cedula,
            p.Celular,
            pr.Descripcion,
            r.Contenido,
            c.nombre curso
FROM respuestas r
INNER JOIN CursoPlaneadoParticipantes cpp
    ON cpp.Id = r.CursoPlaneadoParticipanteId
INNER JOIN CursoPlaneadoes cp
    ON cp.Id = cpp.CursoPlaneadoId
INNER JOIN Participantes p
    ON p.Id = cpp.ParticipanteId
INNER JOIN Cursoes c
    ON c.Id = cp.CursoId
INNER JOIN Preguntas pr
    ON r.preguntaid = pr.preguntaid
WHERE FechaInicio >='20180317' 
AND FechaInicio < '20180318' 
AND r.Contenido = 'SI'
AND r.preguntaid IN (1734,1735,1736)
;
```

Comment: Hola gracia por responder al hacer esta consulta me arroja este error: 
   ` [Err] 42S22 - [SQL Server]El nombre de columna 'preguntaid' no es 
   válido.`

Comment: en tu pregunta no posteaste cuál es el nombre de la columna que contiene el id de la pregunta en la tabla pregunta. Usa ese nombre en la condición de join `ON r.preguntaid = pr.preguntaid`

Answer (score 0):

hazlo con un "in"

```
where respuestas.preguntaid in(1734,1735,1736) And '20180317 23:59:59'
```

de esta manera puedes buscar varios elementos que coincidan con un campo

checa esta página
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp

Comment: Y como relaciono para que muestre los cursos?

Comment: -.- te hace falta ver mas bax.. o mas SQL , lo unico que tienes que hacer es sustituir "*respuestas.preguntaid = 1734*" por 
"*respuestas.preguntaid IN (1734,1735,1736)*"

Comment: cursoes.nombre curso debe tener el nombre del curso